# Maven deployment to heroku error

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a java/maven application to heroku platform, everything goes ok until I try to access the result link.
 Despite of successfully build the link I open shows this error:

```
        An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

        If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. 

>  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 6.571 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-06T20:06:45+00:00
       [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/164M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 87.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Thanks :D

Comment: What do the application logs say?  Not the build logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error. But your build output shows that you don't have any process types defined (which means heroku won't know how to run your app):

```
Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

You'll need to create a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and add it to your Git repo. Most Java apps have a Procfile that contains something like:

```
web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Application Logs:


2016-10-06T22:15:32.100143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=1296ef81-571d-47e5-98dc-5d03903cc510 fwd="202.12.102.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-06T22:15:33.413012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=d141a43d-6b8c-49f6-beda-3015cb6ed095 fwd="202.12.102.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:00:23.973558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=a67f3093-7ca0-4eaa-9a49-0eb1a0d51fd8 fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:00:24.773937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=e2566da5-e666-46ea-b8bb-e4bb74c7758b fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:03:28.357036+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 28740e1 by 95felipeg@gmail.com
2016-10-07T00:03:28.357036+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by 95felipeg@gmail.com
2016-10-07T00:03:28.543707+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-07T00:03:28.543712+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-07T00:08:48.878843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=cb9c2a83-0ebf-4d83-89a6-d273b4d70fd6 fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:08:49.400040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=18093f32-39c7-4085-90e4-a04e84e4f9d7 fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:11:54.778061+00:00 heroku[api]: Set maintenance mode on by 95felipeg@gmail.com
2016-10-06T22:15:32.100143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=1296ef81-571d-47e5-98dc-5d03903cc510 fwd="202.12.102.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-06T22:15:33.413012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=d141a43d-6b8c-49f6-beda-3015cb6ed095 fwd="202.12.102.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:00:23.973558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=a67f3093-7ca0-4eaa-9a49-0eb1a0d51fd8 fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:00:24.773937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=e2566da5-e666-46ea-b8bb-e4bb74c7758b fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:03:28.357036+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 28740e1 by 95felipeg@gmail.com
2016-10-07T00:03:28.357036+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by 95felipeg@gmail.com
2016-10-07T00:03:28.543707+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-07T00:03:28.543712+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-07T00:08:48.878843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=cb9c2a83-0ebf-4d83-89a6-d273b4d70fd6 fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:08:49.400040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurant-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=18093f32-39c7-4085-90e4-a04e84e4f9d7 fwd="200.144.94.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-07T00:11:54.778061+00:00 heroku[api]: Set maintenance mode on by 95felipeg@gmail.com
```